# Heroku login issue on Node js

Tags: node.js, heroku

I was deploying my app on heroku fine but now I am getting the following error:

```
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit: 
heroku: Waiting for login... done
/home/ubuntu/.local/share/heroku/client/7.18.9/node_modules/@oclif/errors/lib/index.js:29
        throw err;
        ^

Error: timed out
    at Object.error (/home/ubuntu/.local/share/heroku/client/7.18.9/node_modules/@oclif/errors/lib/index.js:22:17)
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/home/ubuntu/.local/share/heroku/client/7.18.9/node_modules/@heroku-cli/command/lib/login.js:27:38)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:324:15)
    at processTimers (timers.js:268:5)
```

What does it mean and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. I had to type

heroku login -i

Apparently the -i stands for interactive. I had to find the answer buried in code a tutorial i have access to. I figured i would post this here in case it helps others. Hope this helps!